# Setting up Graphite on a server without root access, internet

Tags: system, monitoring, root, graphite, alerts

I'm working on setting up Graphite for graphing metrics in a closed system where:

1. I do not have root access
2. I cannot access the internet for security reasons.

I'm trying to figure out how I'm going to handle this installation by purely scp-ing over installation files. Any ideas and suggestions would be helpful.

Cheers.

Comment: i have added details to the answer. Did you figure out a way without root access?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. In order to generate ICMP packets one needs to open a so called "RAW socket". On most UNIX systems only the superuser (root) may open such sockets. `carbon-cache.py` (which collects the metrics) *needs* root privileges to initiate the socket connections and so forth.

PS: You can drop them to any other user later by indicating so in `carbon.conf`, but i don't see how that could help you out here.